# What is Text-Wall Effect in web design?

Tags: website-design, web

I have seen this in 4th point,  TIA
https://uxplanet.org/10-beginner-tricks-to-improve-your-website-design-f26bb465f745

Comment: Please explain abbreviations like `TIA` and rephrase your question in the question (although given as summary in title) What is the _4th point_ ? Use quote formatting if appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

As used in that page, it refers to what magazine editors will call “wall of text” – that is, a solid block of text with no spaces or other design elements to break it up. It’s often taken as a sign of poor writing, as it usually means that the text in question is formatted as a single paragraph, and likely will not be read by many people.

An example of a wall of text, deliberately created as such, can be found at [Reddit’s r/WallOfText](https://www.reddit.com/r/WallOfText/comments/2ieklc/pointless_wall_of_text_i_made/).

The wall of text/grey wall effect can be avoided simply by adding white space (such as paragraph breaks) at appropriate intervals; other design elements that break up walls of text are images, “pull quotes”, headings and subheadings, or lists (bulleted or numbered) – basically, anything that's *not* text and breaks up the solid block.

Comment: Clear description of the term within 3 logically coherent paragraphs. Do you have further contextual references to read more about it?